# How many correct "review" tests are needed to clean your history?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I am constantly reviewing the queues and after some wrongdoings in the first weeks (and bans for that matter) I roughly was tested like 10 times the last 3 weeks. I managed all of them but failed lately at one test.

Now it seems that no matter how much tests you pass, one failure triggers like a long-timespan ban (4 weeks for me) as if the passes just don't matter.

Is this really the intended behavior? To me it feels a bit weird. Can't be that one fail results in such a ban.

Comment: This was me not long ago, I've pulled back to reviewing a handful a week to avoid any problems but was under the impression that over time the wrong flags would reduce, this suggests it doesn't or it does at a much slower rate than expected.

Comment: If your last failure was less than a month ago, failing again it's going to review ban you again. The number of passed audits is irrelevant.

Comment: Martijn's answer on the linked question is pretty good. Best advice: slow down.

Comment: ok. Here we go. Thanks for showing the duplicate and for the comments here. IMO this system doesnt work the way it should. You will get punished if you review a lot because chances are high that you fail at some point. It doesnt take into account that you pass a whole lot of review-tests and that you do much work. It just looks at this 30 day span and punishes you on test-fail. No matter how much you reviewed and how much you passed. This makes people stop reviewing in the long run. Algos are bad!

Comment: @Marc: incorrect reviews are worse than no review at all. As Shog says: slow down.

Comment: It's not about punishment. Everyone fails an audit sooner or later. I've failed audits. I've gotten banned! Fatigue isn't a judgement on your character, it's a sign that it's time to take a break. Slow down and take care of yourself; there's no need to rush, no call to wear yourself out on this.

Comment: @Shog9 not everyone.

Comment: I will slow down. Thanks for feedback.